# Cant get the Selenium expression "IsElementPresent" to work with C#

Tags: c#, selenium

```
try
{
    Assert.AreEqual(true, driver.IsElementPresent(By.Id("s_m_HeaderContent_MainTitle")));
}
catch (AssertionException e)
{
    verificationErrors.Append(e.Message);
}

// ...

private bool IsElementPresent(By by)
{
    try
    {
        driver.FindElements(by);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IsElementPresent` isn't a method on the `Driver`.

```
Assert.AreEqual(true, driver.IsElementPresent(By.Id("s_m_HeaderContent_MainTitle")));
```

should be:

```
Assert.AreEqual(true, IsElementPresent(By.Id("s_m_HeaderContent_MainTitle")));
```

This is because it's a `private` method within that class.

Comment: Give us more information - what's the error? What's not working? What happens vs not happens? Not enough information to go on, so please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assert.AreEqual(true, IsElementPresent(By.Id("s_m_HeaderContent_MainTitle"),driver));

public bool IsElementPresent(By by, IWebDriver driver)
{
    try
    {
        driver.FindElement(by);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```